# Django migrations - Get current app name in RunPython function

Tags: django, django-migrations

One of my migrations has the additional function to be run using `RunPython`. This message's purpose is only to show a happy message to user. The only problem is, that I need to show an app name, in which current migration was created and run. Is this somewhat possible?

**My code**:

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


def happy_message(apps, schema_editor):
    print('A happy message from migration inside app named {}')


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='mymodel',
            name='rank_no',
            field=models.IntegerField(null=True),
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(
            happy_message,
            migrations.RunPython.noop
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: You can name you're migration using [--name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/#workflow) flag option

Answer (score 3):

You can monkey-patch the `code` (and `reverse_code`) attribute of your custom `RunPython` to support an extra argument `app_label`:

```
from django.db import migrations


class AppAwareRunPython(migrations.RunPython):

    # MonkeyPatch the `code` call with a lambda that add an extra argument `app_label`
    def database_forwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
        mp_code = self.code
        self.code = lambda apps, se: mp_code(apps, se, app_label)
        super().database_forwards(app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state)

    # Same for backwards if you want to display message when unapplying the migration
    def database_backwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
        if self.reverse_code:
            mp_reverse_code = self.reverse_code
            self.reverse_code = lambda apps, se: mp_reverse_code(apps, se, app_label)
        super().database_backwards(app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state)

    # Add the etra argument to noop
    @staticmethod
    def noop(apps, schema_editor, app_label=None):
        migrations.RunPython.noop(apps, schema_editor)


# This function can't be used with classic RunPython unless you put `app_label=None` and test its value
def happy_message(apps, schema_editor, app_label):
    print(f'A happy message from migration inside app named {app_label}')


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    operations = [
        AppAwareRunPython(happy_message, AppAwareRunPython.noop),
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the classic Django file architecture, then your migration file should be located in `project_dir/app_dir/migrations/0001_migration_file.py`.

Then, you can simply get the application directory name:

```django
from os.path import basename, dirname

def happy_message(apps, schema_editor):
    app_name = basename(dirname(dirname(__file__)))
    print(f'A happy message from migration inside app named {app_name}')
```

Comment: That would work. However it seems to be a little hacky.

Comment: Yes it is, but I didn't find a way to retreive the "app_label" attribute from the Migration object from a RunPython yet ^^

Comment: I'm not proud, but here's the equivalent code using the new [pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), available from Python 3.4 up: `app_name = Path(__file__).parents[1].name`